# Creating composite band image with Sentinel 2 data using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, error-000732, list, composite, batch

As we know sentinel satellite data have many sub folder. I want to create composite band of each datasets with the band 2, band 3, band 4, band 8 which are located in one folder(10m) and band 11, band 12 which are located in other folder(20m).I am making a arcpy code for that but code was not run correctly. Here is the code

```
import arcpy, os

basepath = "L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image_raw\New folder"

endswith = ("_B02_10m.jp2", "_B03_10m.jp2", "_B04_10m.jp2", "_B08_10m.jp2", "_B11_20m.jp2", "_B12_20m.jp2")

output = "L:\Arcpy\Data\Layer_stack"

rasterlist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basepath):
    for rasterlayer in files:
        if rasterlayer.endswith(endswith):
           #print(os.path.join(root, rasterlayer))
           rasterlist.append(rasterlayer)
           print "image:" + str(rasterlist)
name = os.path.join(output, rasterlist[1].split("_")[0] + ".img")
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rasterlist, name)
print(rasterlist)
```

I was trying these code but output is not created. It gave this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "L:\Arcpy\Py_script\composite_band_script_1.py", line 35, in 
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rasterlist, name)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 13647, in CompositeBands
raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Rasters: Dataset T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2;T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2;T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2;T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2;T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2;T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2;T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2;T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2;T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2;T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2;T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2;T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B12_20m.jp2;T45QUD_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2;T45QUD_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2;T45QUD_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2;T45QUD_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2;T45QUD_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2;T45QUD_20210102T045209_B12_20m.jp2;T45QVD_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2;T45QVD_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2;T45QVD_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2;T45QVD_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2;T45QVD_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2;T45QVD_20210102T045209_B12_20m.jp2 does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CompositeBands).

Comment: The three lines after `print "rasterlist:"...` should not be indentated

Comment: What is "not run correctly.", do you get any errors?

Comment: Above error is showing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use os to list the bands. [Composite bands](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/composite-bands.htm) wants a semi-colon separated string with the inputs, not a list (use [join](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/) to change it). Your indentations after the if statement are incorrect. And add `r` in front of the paths:

```
import os, arcpy

tile = r'C:\folder\S2A_MSIL2A_20200322T102021_N0214_R065_T33VWG_20200322T110445.SAFE'

filelist = []
for root, folders, files in os.walk(tile):
    for file in files:
        fullPath = os.path.join(root, file)
        if os.path.isfile(fullPath) and fullPath.endswith('.jp2') and any(substring in fullPath for substring in ['B02_10m', 'B03_10m', 'B04_10m', 'B11_20m', 'B12_20m']):
            filelist.append(fullPath)
filelist.sort()

outFile = os.path.join(r"C:\Composite_band\Layer_stack", os.path.basename(filelist[0]).replace('.jp2', '.img'))
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(';'.join(filelist), outFile)
```

Comment: I have done some changes in the above code as per your guidance but this time I am getting this error : rasterlist:['D:\\Composite_band\\New folder\\S2A_MSIL2A_20210104T044201_N0214_R033_T45QVD_20210104T063322.SAFE\\GRANULE\\L2A_T45QVD_A028916_20210104T044202\\IMG_DATA\\R10m\\T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Composite_band\composite_band_script_1.py", line 29, in <module>
    name = os.path.join(output, rasterlist[1].split("_")[0] + ".img")
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The problem is when I am printing only image like print(image), it is gave all selected band from different folder but when I am run others line then its give me a error.

Comment: What is the error message. You still havent got r in front of your paths...

Comment: I put r in front of path on original code but this time in output folder only band 2 is generated but I want composite band for every file. This time I am getting this error: ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000725: Output Raster: Dataset D:\Composite_band\Layer_stack\T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.img already exists.
Failed to execute (CompositeBands).

Comment: I made changes in above code as your guiedence

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. You are trying to execute composite bands for each band

Comment: I am trying to do with rasterlist where selected bands are stored.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why you are seeing that error on that line try replacing:

```
name = os.path.join(output, rasters[0].split("_")[0] + ".img")
```

with:

```
print(rasters[0])
name = os.path.join(output, rasters[0].split("_")[0] + ".img")
```

I think you will find that a list is printed when your code is anticipating that `rasters[0]` will be a string.

Comment: I am trying those two lines as you said but I got the same error.

Comment: That is to be expected. Did you get a list or a string printed?

Comment: I am getting this error: [[]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Composite_band\module1.py", line 31, in <module>
    name = os.path.join(output, rasters[0].split("_")[0] + ".img")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Did you get a list or a string printed before the error message?

Comment: I am getting empty list like this:  [[]]

Comment: That means that you cannot split it.  You could if it was a string.  If you did not want it to be a list then you need to look at why your earlier code made it one.

Comment: It's actually a list of one empty list by the look of it.

Comment: print "rasters: "+str(rasters)
            name = os.path.join(output, rasters[1].split("_")[0] + ".img") this time I was add those line but get the error:rasters: [[]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Composite_band\module1.py", line 31, in <module>
    name = os.path.join(output, rasters[1].split("_")[0] + ".img")
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Add r in front of the paths